# postgreSQL именование индексов и ключей

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите как у вас принято именовать индексы и ключи в PostgreSQL.

Comment: `idx_таблица_поля` Большинство таких имён вполне укладывается в отпущенные по умолчанию 63 символа. Если нет - используются сокращения имён таблицы и полей, но так, чтобы они оставались распознаваемы.

Comment: Но поля, то приходится именовать через подчеркивание, т.к. все в lowcase и в итоге все сливается..

Comment: У меня почему-то не сливается.

Comment: Ну, вот есть у меня таблица quik.params и поля price_min_us_previous_wa, yield_at_prev_wa_pri, previous_legal_close_price, тогда индекс по нему будет ix_quik_params_price_min_us_previous_wa_yield_at_prev_wa_pri_previous_legal_close_price. У меня в глазах рябит и ограничение на длину скорее получишь.

Comment: Ааа... ну при таких именах полей ещё и индексы делать говорящими - есссно не выйдет. Тогда делай тупо `idx_таблица_1`, `idx_таблица_2`, ... да и не парься. Кому надо - залезет в DDL и посмотрит.